# DateTime ASP .Net Core 2.0 (C#) and Net Framework VB (4.7.1)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue with the data type / Date Time

Solution in Visual Studio 2017:
I’m working with .Net Core Web Application (ASP .NET Core 2.0 (C#) & Angular) as the main project and I´ve also added to the solution other projects, class library in Visual Basic (Framework 4.7.1).

The problem with the data types Date and Datetime. Is when trying to communicate between my projects. When I try to send this data type from one project to another, it doesn’t recognize the variable and it throws the following exception: Internal error in the expression evaluator.
It seems that core 2.0 and Framework 4.7.1 doesn´t like each other if you try to work with them in the same solution.

The data types Date and Datatime works perfectly fine in C# CORE 2.0 (the main project) but stop working when you send it as a Date or Datetime variable to the vb.net Framework 4.7.1, projects imported to the solution. Throwing the exception previously described.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: English only please.

Comment: "Internal error in the expression evaluator." That sounds like it's part of the debugger, not in your compiled code. If that's not the case, please be clearer about exactly what you're doing.